# Ubuntu CMake what path to add to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

My OS is Ubuntu. I would like to change from QT4 to QT5 in my project. The native package though is 4.x version in Ubuntu right now.

I have downloaded the Linux installer from QT homepage and installed QT5.4  under `/opt/Qt/5.4/`

This path is not found by

```
find_package (Qt5 REQUIRED)
```

I tried adding

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/opt/QT/5.4;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
```

to my `CMAKELIST.txt` but that does not help.

Where do I have to link, or am I using the wrong syntax?

Some edits after hint with calling:

```
 cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/QT/5.4/gcc_64/ ../src/
```

I also have deleted the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH variable.
I still get the same error:

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
 Found package configuration file:
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake
 but it set Qt5_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt5" is considered to be NOT
 FOUND.  Reason given by package:

 The Qt5 package requires at least one component
```

I dont know why this is happening after reading https://blogs.kde.org/2008/12/12/how-get-cmake-find-what-you-want-it
. There it is stated, that the path will be searched before the default search directories. The path I used seems to be right now:

```
/opt/QT/5.4/gcc_64/
```

Adding subfolder gcc_64 must be right, as this subfolder has "lib", "include" ect as subfolders.

I remeber that I have called also

```
sudo apt-get install QT5-default
```

some time ago. This did not help, I needed the installer from QT. Although I removed qt5-default again to prevent cmake from finding the wrong package configuration file, the same error appears.

See discussion below, moved to here:
[Cmake and QT5 - Include only takes one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252909/cmake-and-qt5-include-only-takes-one-argument)

Comment: Should the ';' in your set() statement be there?

Comment: I think set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/opt/QT/5.4;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}") is the right syntax but not sure

Comment: `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is the path to find .cmake files not to find installed packages.

Comment: You can start with simple example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989448/implementing-qt-project-through-cmake/25990278#25990278 , I hope this helps you.

Comment: You need replace `find_package (Qt5 REQUIRED)` on `find_package (Qt5Core REQUIRED)`, or `find_package (Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)`.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, i.e. invoke

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/QT/5.4 <path_to_source>
```

at the root of your build tree. Then you can use `find_package(Qt5 ...)` etc. See also the [Qt5 cmake docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html).

Rough distinction within you focus:

- `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is for "general" [inclusion of files](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_MODULE_PATH) and "FindXXX.cmake" files in `find_package(... MODULE)`.
- `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` has a [special meaning](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) in the context of `find_package(... CONFIG)`.

### After addition of new content

this is a new error and thus should require a new question. if you had that error before you'd have already found the Qt5 config.cmake file :-)

anyways, as the error tells you

> The Qt5 package requires at least one component

you need to specify a *component* of the Qt5 package. As the [cmake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) say, you need to use the find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core ...) interface so that cmake (better: the logic of Qt5 FindQt5.cmake) knows what to look for. that will give you the targets `Qt5::Widgets` etc to use/link against.
i dont know if the syntax `find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)` works, could be equivalent.

Comment: Your path doesn't work fine for me, instead `/opt/qt/5.4/gcc_64` works fine. (Kubuntu 14.10).

Comment: jup! i just used the path @BuddhaWithBigBelly provided.. depending on architecture/compiler there might be different subdirectories.

Comment: @daniel.wirtz moved to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252909/cmake-and-qt5-include-only-takes-one-argument

Comment: hey @BuddaWithBigBelly, good to open a new question for the next problem! plz dont forget to mark this one accepted if you think it's answered, or tell me what else you find unresolved :-)