# Cmake and QT5 - Include only takes one argument

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

coming from this topic:
[Ubuntu CMake what path to add to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247137/ubuntu-cmake-what-path-to-add-to-cmake-module-path)

I try to get QT5 in my project running, as QT4 does not allow me to include QWebView.

Following the guides from the mentioned topics I now have a CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project (simpleTree)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core) 
find_package (VTK REQUIRED)
find_package (PCL 1.8.0 REQUIRED)

include_directories (${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories (${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions (${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set (project_SOURCES export/exportply.cpp export/writecsv.cpp main.cpp
         controller.cpp 
         gui/pclviewer.cpp
         import/importpcd.cpp 
         method/SphereFollowing.cpp 
         Model/crown.cpp 
         Model/Cylinder.cpp 
         Model/Segment.cpp 
         Model/Tree.cpp)
set (project_HEADERS controller.h 
         export/writecsv.h
         export/exportply.h
         gui/pclviewer.h
         import/importpcd.h 
         method/SphereFollowing.h 
         Model/crown.h 
         Model/Cylinder.h 
         Model/Segment.h 
         Model/Tree.h)
set (project_FORMS   gui/pclviewer.ui)
set (VTK_LIBRARIES vtkRendering vtkGraphics vtkHybrid QVTK)

QT5_WRAP_CPP (project_HEADERS_MOC   ${project_HEADERS})
QT5_WRAP_UI  (project_FORMS_HEADERS ${project_FORMS})

INCLUDE (${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS (${QT_DEFINITIONS})
ADD_EXECUTABLE (simpleTree ${project_SOURCES}
               ${project_FORMS_HEADERS}
               ${project_HEADERS_MOC})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (simpleTree ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES}       ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

I get the following error, after switching QT4 lines to QT5:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:36 (INCLUDE):
include called with wrong number of arguments.  Include only takes one
file.
```

So this tells me that the variable QT_USE_FILE is now a list, which it was not before. Not sure if this is right, and not sure what I can do.

Thanks
Jan

Answer (score 8):

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:36 (INCLUDE):
include called with wrong number of arguments.  Include only takes one
file.
```

It means that variable `QT_USE_FILE` is empty.

In CMake with Qt5 you should use macro [qt5_use_modules](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) instead of `QT_USE_FILE` and `QT_LIBRARIES`.

So in your `CMakeLists.txt` you need to remove line:
`INCLUDE (${QT_USE_FILE})`
change line:
`TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (simpleTree ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})`
on the:
`TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (simpleTree ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})`
and add line:
`qt5_use_modules (simpleTree Widgets)`

**UPD**:
For now using `qt5_use_modules` is deprecated and `target_link_libraries simpleTree Qt5::Widgets` should be used instead (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989448/implementing-qt-project-through-cmake/25990278#25990278)).