# What to use instead of `qt5_use_modules`?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

The [Qt 5 CMake manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) states that the `qt5_use_modules` macro is deprecated:

> This macro is obsolete. Use target_link_libraries with IMPORTED targets instead.

... But `qt5_use_modules` does more than simply specify link libraries: it specifies include directories, necessary compile flags, and more (see the full description in the linked documentation above).

Assuming, then, that the variable `QTMODULES` contains some list of Qt modules that should be used for a project, what is the "recommended" way to replace the following "deprecated" CMake line?

```
qt5_use_modules(${myProjectName} ${QTMODULES})
```

The following does NOT work, primarily because it does not add any Qt include paths:

```
    target_link_libraries(${myProjectName} IMPORTED ${QTMODULES})
```

Does the `QTMODULES` variable need to be manually iterated over, so that `include_directories` can be called for each individual module name? This seems like a major step backward from `qt5_use_modules`, which is simple and "just works." Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17):

The message about using IMPORTED targets actually refers to the generated targets that Qt5's CMake modules provide for you, not that you should be setting the IMPORTED property on the `target_link_libraries` macro.  For example, something like:

```
target_link_libraries(${myProjectName} Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)
```

will take care of adding all the necessary include paths, link paths, and libraries for using the `Qt5Core` and `Qt5Widgets` modules.

Comment: That still seems to require separating out each name from the variable containing the list of modules I'd like to use and appending `Qt5::` to each one. Is there any particular reason why this is preferable to simply using `qt5_use_modules`?

Comment: That *is* interesting, though, that you can get `target_link_libraries` to add include paths, etc.

Comment: Depending on the format of the list, you may be able to do some regex on it, or iterate through the list to build a new variable in the right format...

Comment: Right, and I feel confident that I *could* do that, but what advantage does that have versus using `qt5_use_modules`, which already does that for me?

Comment: Using Qt5:: is just newer and is the Cmake 2.8.11+ way to do it.

Comment: @TimZaman .....so CMake deprecates things just because they're not shiny and new, regardless of whether the "new way" is better or not?

Comment: In this case it's actually Qt5 that decided to deprecate it -- see lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreMacros.cmake for reference

Comment: @Zrax Interesting-- thank you. I don't see a comment in that file about *why* it's deprecated, though; any idea why that is or where I could find such an explanation?

Comment: Interesting indeed -- it turns out that it was marked deprecated in qtbase.git because `qt4_use_modules` was marked deprecated by CMake after all.  It appears they (cmake) introduced `qt4_use_modules` for 2.8.10 and then deprecated it less than a year later for 2.8.12.  I can't tell why they deprecated it from just looking at git history, but I suspect they chose to only support their preferred interface going forward rather than maintaining two very different ones.

Comment: `qtN_use_modules()` had a lot of problems, not the least of which is that it was "global". Using `target_link_libraries()` with the IMPORTED Qt:: targets, you could link each of your targets with a _different_ set of Qt modules. Additionally, `qtN_use_modules()` [only picked up modules in the Qt install dir](https://github.com/qtwebkit/qtwebkit/wiki/Using-QtWebKit-in-your-project#cmake), which was a problem for external modules like QtWebKit which could be installed at a different path.