# cmake qt automoc - getting automoc'ed files as variable

Tags: qt, cmake, moc

Is it possible to get the automoc'ed files (Qt moc)? That would be great because i could put it on a source_group.

I'm using cmake 3.4.1

Thanks in advance
Tonka

Comment: You should use explicit `qt5_wrap_cpp(HEADERS_MOCED ${HEADERS})` instead of `automoc`.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989448/implementing-qt-project-through-cmake/25990278#25990278) is a complete example.