# CMake AUTOMOC with files on different folders

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, moc

I have a simple CMake project:

```
proj (project folder)
├── a.h
├── a.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

project(proj)

set( proj_SOURCE
    a.cpp
)

find_package(Qt5Core)

set( proj_LIBRARIES
    Qt5::Core
)

add_library(proj SHARED ${proj_SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(proj ${proj_LIBRARIES})
```

a.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>

class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit A(QObject *parent = 0);
};
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"

A::A(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}
```

and everything compiles great. Next, I tried to move the header file and the source file into different folder as so:

```
proj (project folder)
├── include
│   └── a.h
├── src
│   └── a.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

And tried different configurations of the following calls:

```
include_directories("include")
include_directories("src")

set( proj_SOURCE
    src/a.cpp
)
```

Dosen't matter what I do the compilation fails with variations of

```
a.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl A::metaObject(void)const
" (?metaObject@A@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ) [C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\subclass\build\proj.vcxproj]
a.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl A::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@A
@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z) [C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\subclass\build\proj.vcxproj]
a.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl A::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void *
 *)" (?qt_metacall@A@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) [C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\subclass\build\proj.vcxproj]
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\subclass\build\Debug\proj.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals [C:\Users\me\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\subclass\build\proj.vcxproj]
```

I don't know if I need to set something extra for CMake to work or what the problem is. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989448/implementing-qt-project-through-cmake) answer says that CMake does not work well on this configuration (files on different folders), but maybe there is a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the CMake users list: It seems like on this specific configuration one needs to add the header files to the target. I still dont know exactly why, but code below answers the above question.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

project(proj)

set( proj_SOURCE
    a.cpp
)

# add this
set( proj_HEADER
    include/a.h
)

find_package(Qt5Core)

set( proj_LIBRARIES
    Qt5::Core
)

# modify this
add_library(proj SHARED ${proj_SOURCE} ${proj_HEADER})
target_link_libraries(proj ${proj_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only solution that seems to work for me! It is simple and I see no downside to it... also, `HEADERS` variable of `qmake` reads as if it would put those header files to the project, too, which even more suggests your way