# msvc not generate moc file with CMake automoc

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, cmake

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(source_files
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
    ...
   )

set(header_files
    a.hpp
    b.hpp
    ...
   )

set(Qt_libs
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Gui
    Qt5::Widget
    ...
   )

add_library(demo SHARED ${header_files} ${source_files})
target_link_libraries(demo ${Qt_libs} ...)
set_properties(TARGET demo PROPERTY FOLDER "somewhere")
install(...)
```

I have a sample `CMakeLists.txt` shows above.

The most weird thing is, it won't generate those moc files until I manually modified (like adding a empty line to the file) those header files (where `Q_OBJECT` presents).

The situation not happen every time. But, once it happens, clean build nor deleting whole project file won't help.

I'm using `qt 5.11`, `CMake 3.7`, `Visual Studio 2015`.

Comment: I have problems with `auto_moc` as well (as a lot of others might tell you). I always run a `cmake configure` after adding a new file which needs `moc`

Comment: I had similar problem and could not manage to solve it. So I decided to use the qt5_generate_moc() macro

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151163/cmake-automoc-with-files-on-different-folders/37174028#37174028

Comment: @Mac I have both header and source files added to the target. It seems not produced by handling CMake file wrong because the problem happens only sometimes.

Comment: did u try adding the headers to the solution as described there?

Comment: @Mac Yes, I did

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the global setting with set() which could be overwritten. 
Please use set_target_properties, for example

```
project(exampleProj)
add_executable(exampleProj main.cpp)
set_target_properties(exampleProj
   PROPERTIES
     CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON
     CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try it and posting result later.

Comment: @Ducksoul if you do not have success with this answer, consider updating your question with the contents of your CMakelists.txt file so that the answer may be filled with more context

Comment: this method seems not solving the problem after a few tries. And my Cmake file is pretty much the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151163/cmake-automoc-with-files-on-different-folders?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Ducksoul I need your snippet so I can see if set_target_properties was used on a valid target . Excluding filenames of your sources would still produce a minimum, verifiable, example if the contents are sensitive

Comment: @Ducksoul do you have #include "a.moc" appended at the bottom of your a.cpp file (assuming a is the name of the Q_OBJECT) ? If not can you try doing that? I reread your question and I am looking at "it won't generate those moc files until I manually modified"

Comment: I tried `a.moc` in source file before with no luck. The only solution is modified those file where `Q_OBJECT` exists. I currently use a pre-build refresh script for those files as a temporary solution.