# QQuick with CMake: style does not work

Tags: cmake, qtquickcontrols2

I am willing to use styling within Qt Quick Controls 2 and together with a CMake project in C++. And I am having a hard time to get the colors right.

The C++, qml and styling code comes from [the qt blog](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/06/more-of-qt-quick-designer-and-qt-quick-controls-2/) and is working fine so long as I use a **.pro** project file but when I turn to CMakeLists.txt I do not manage to get the colors right (I believe they are the default dark / purple colors rather than dark / orange).

In the **.pro** project my **main.cpp** looks like this:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickStyle>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

My **qml.qrc** file lookes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>CustomLabel.qml</file>
        <file>PageBackground.qml</file>
        <file>SideBar.qml</file>
        <file>SideBarForm.ui.qml</file>
        <file>Light.qml</file>
        <file>LightForm.ui.qml</file>
        <file>Heating.qml</file>
        <file>HeatingForm.ui.qml</file>
        <file>Security.qml</file>
        <file>SecurityForm.ui.qml</file>
        <file>qtquickcontrols2.conf</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And my **qtquickcontrols2.conf** file like this:

```
[Controls]
Style=Material

[Universal]
Theme=Dark
Accent=DeepOrange

[Material]
Theme=Dark
Accent=DeepOrange
```

Now my CMake project folder contains exactly the same files (it is actually a copy and paste of the **.pro** project folder) except that I have removed the **.pri** and **.pro** files and it now contains a **CMakeLists.txt** which looks like this:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.9)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)

# Projet. 
project(MyQtQuick)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# Find dependencies.
set(QT_DIR ../DevRoot/Dependencies/Qt/v5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64)

# Prepare project for Qt. 
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON) # Find includes in corresponding build directories.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) # Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${QT_DIR})

find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Gui)
find_package(Qt5OpenGL)
find_package(Qt5Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Qml REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5QuickControls2 REQUIRED)

# List sources.
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_sources
    main.cpp
)

qt5_add_resources(RCC_SOURCES qml.qrc)

# Headers.
include_directories(
    .
    )

# Output library.
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})

# Linker.
qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Core Gui OpenGL QuickControls2)
```

Files **main.cpp**, **qml.qrc** and ****qtquickcontrols2.conf** remain the same (except for the path to **main.qml** in **main.cpp** which I had to change from **"qrc:/main.qml"** to **"../main.qml" as **qrc:** does not work with CMake - no idea why).

Now when I compile and execute the CMake project I get the application executed but the colors are bad, the application is rendered with the default dark/pink colors rather the dark/orange colors defined in **qtquickcontrols2.conf**. My **.pro** project compiles and runs smoothly though.

I have looked for hours over the internet and could not find any answer. I have also realized that I could use **QQuickView** rather than **QQmlApplicationEngine** to load my qml file (no idea what is the difference but I have tested the alternative code), though it did not help.

Do you have any of what is going on with my CMake project?

Additionally (and this is a secondary question): do you have any idea why I cannot write **"qrc:/main.qml"** when using the CMake project? In the **.pro** project I can use **"qrc:/main.qml"** and my qml files are neatly listed below the **.qrc** file in the project tree, which is not the case when using the CMake project.

Comment: 1. Why do you need: `set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)`? 2. Why do you need: `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)`? 3. Instead of plenty `find_package` and `qt5_use_modules` try `find_package (Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::OpenGL Qt5::QuickControls2)`. 4. Why do you need `include_directories(.)`? 5. `add_executable` must contain also compiled resources: `${RCC_SOURCES}`, etc...

Comment: Hi Glutton and thanks for your answer. You propose to replace replace the **qt5_use_modules** by **target_link_libraries** but isn't that more or less the same? Moreover you also need the many **find_package** to get **target_link_libraries** working, no?

Comment: `but isn't that more or less the same?` more or less this is the same, but `qt5_use_modules` is deprecated. `Moreover you also need the many find_package`, IMO, no, only one (usually `Core` or `Widgets`). I hope my other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989448/implementing-qt-project-through-cmake/25990278#25990278) can be helpful .

Comment: If you didn't manage to get QRC working with CMake, then that is causing the problem. qtquickcontrols2.conf is only loaded from QRC.

Comment: @jpnurmi: good point

Comment: @Glutton: thanks a lot your answers were very helpful, things now work fine ;)

Comment: You should get the file **qrc_qml.cpp** within your build folder. Does it exist? Are there two or three sections for **qtquickcontrols2.conf** within?

Answer (score 13):

First just add this to your cmake file

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick QuickControls2 REQUIRED)
```

than add this

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick Qt5::QuickControls2)
```

in your CmakeLists.txt