# Converting Qt project with a .pro file to project using CMake - Problems with moc

Tags: qt, cmake, moc

I have a project which compiles fine when I build it with a `.pro` file with QtCreator.  I am trying to convert it to `cmake`, but have run into an issue.

EDITED WITH MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE:

Project folder structure:

```
src/foo.cpp   --> #include "ui_foo.h"
src/bar.cpp   --> #include "bar.moc"
inc/foo.h   
ui/foo.ui
```

Expected compilation flow (observed flow when using `qmake`):

```
(1)  moc  inc/foo.h              -o moc_foo.cpp
(2)  moc  src/bar.cpp            -o bar.moc
(3)  uic  ui/foo.ui              -o ui_foo.h
(4)  gcc  src/foo.cpp            -o foo.o
(5)  gcc  src/bar.cpp            -o bar.o
(6)  gcc  moc_foo.cpp            -o moc_foo.o
(7)  ld   foo.o bar.o moc_foo.o  -o foobar
```

**CMakeLists.txt(1)**:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON )
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON )
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON )
add_executable(foobar src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp)
```

`moc_foo.cpp` is not created (step 1 & 6 are missed) and doesn't get added to `add_executable` in step 7.  Undefined references to vtable occur because of missing object. I think this is because foo.cpp and foo.h are in different folders.

**CMakeLists.txt(2)**:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON )
qt5_wrap_cpp(foobar_moc inc/foo.h src/bar.cpp)
qt5_wrap_ui (foobar_ui  ui/foo.ui)
add_executable(foobar src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp ${foobar_moc} ${foobar_ui})
```

`moc_bar.cpp` is generated instead of `bar.moc` in step 2.  I get a compiler error because `bar.moc` cannot be found in step 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making your own life unnecessary hard by trying to moc a .cpp file.

Despite the name `qt5_wrap_cpp` actually takes *header files* as its argument and invokes the moc to generate matching cpp files:

```
qt5_wrap_cpp(foobar_moc inc/foo.h)

# ${foobar_moc} will contain the name 
# of the .cpp file created for foo.h
# which we pass to add_executable()
```

Note that typically you will have a `foo.cpp` source file lying around somewhere as well, which together with the `.cpp` generated by the moc provides the full implementation for the class defined in `foo.h`.

Now, if you really want to invoke the moc on a `.cpp` file, the procedure is slightly different. Here, since the class definition is no longer in a header file, the source file generated by the moc cannot access the class definition it refers to. As a result, the generated source file can no longer be compiled on its own. Instead, you need to pull it into the original source file *after* the class definition using `#include`, which is not very nice.

What's worse is that for CMake to invoke the moc command, the generated source file still needs to be part of the dependency chain somewhere, which makes everything quite ugly.

We will use the [`qt5_generate_moc`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html#qt5core-macros) command to invoke the moc on `bar.cpp` (as `qt5_wrap_cpp` would also add the generated source to the build, which would break):

```
qt5_generate_moc(src/bar.cpp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bar.moc)
```

Note that we place the generated file in the binary tree to not pollute the source tree with generated files. If you have set an [`AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR.html#prop_tgt:AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR), you might want to put the generated file there instead. In order to allow the `#include` to find the generated file, we add the binary tree to the include directories for our project:

```
target_include_directories(foobar PUBLIC ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

And finally, we need a custom target for the build step dependency. Without this, the moc command would never actually get invoked:

```
add_custom_target(moc_dummy DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bar.moc)
add_dependencies(foobar moc_dummy)
```

Bottom line: Just move all your class definitions to header files and then moc those. There's no disadvantage and you will save yourself lots of ugly boilerplate.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.  I'm trying not to change this old code at all.  It worked with qmake, so I figured there must be a way to make it work with CMAKE without changing the code.  qt5_generate_moc was exactly what I needed.  I didn't see it in the cmake documentation and I guess I just didn't notice it in the Qt documentation.  That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do would be to add [AUTOMOC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html) property, and let [CMake handle QT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#manual:cmake-qt(7)) mocs automatically

`set_target_properties(MyProj PROPERTIES AUTOMOC TRUE)`

Comment: Wow, that actually worked.  Thanks for the link.  I wasn't sure how to use AUTOMOC.  
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25990278/1723954) post which suggested the `qt5_wrap_cpp` gave more control and said there were some problems with AUTOMOC so I didn't try.  I ended up needing to use AUTOMOC and `qt5_wrap_ui` as AUTOUIC had some problems.

Comment: Wait. It didn't quite work.  AUTOMOC found `#include "qttelnet.moc"` and generated it correctly from `qttelnet.cpp`, however I also have `.h` files in a separate directory from `.cpp` files which require `moc_foo.cpp`.  Because those files are in different AUTOMOC fails to generate the moc.  That's what the `qt5_cpp_wrap()` solved.