# Can't include ui-file from linked library using CMake's autouic

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake

I have a CMake project which I simplified to find the root of my error.
The project has a single CMakeLists.txt file that adds a library and an executable, which links to the library.
Both the library and the executable include ui-files. In order to generate header-files of the ui-files, the variable `CMAKE_AUTOUIC` is used.
Both, the library and the executable are able to include their *own* ui-files: They are found inside the subdirectory `[projectname]_autogen\include_Debug` of my build directory.
However, another file in my executable includes a file from the library, which in turns includes a ui-file. Here I get the error:

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'ui_MainWidget.h': No such file or directory  QtGUI
\QtGUI\src\QtWidgets\include\MainWidget.h   5
```

My project looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.14 FATAL_ERROR)

project(QtGUI)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

add_library(QtWidgets
    QtWidgets/source/MainWidget.cpp
    QtWidgets/include/MainWidget.h
    QtWidgets/include/MainWidget.ui
)
target_link_libraries(QtWidgets
    PUBLIC
        Qt5::Widgets
        Qt5::Core
        Qt5::Gui
)
target_include_directories(QtWidgets
    PUBLIC
        QtWidgets/include
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    Main/include/MainWindow.h
    Main/include/MainWindow.ui
    Main/source/MainWindow.cpp
    Main/source/Main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        QtWidgets
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        Main/include
)
```

And the `MainWindow.cpp` file from the project `QtGUI`, where the error occurs:

```
#include "MainWindow.h" // inside this project
#include "MainWidget.h" // inside the linked library 'QtWidgets'

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{ 
...
```

The `MainWidget.h` looks like this

```
// Qt Includes
#include <ui_MainWidget.h> // inside this project
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui
{
    class MainWidget;
}

class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
...
```

What am I missing here?
I know that it would be cleaner to split the CMakeLists.txt and have an own CMakeLists.txt inside the linked library and move the `add_library` stuff there (and do the same for the executable, e.g. an `application`-directory) but I think this example makes it easier to understand the structure.

**Edit / Addition**

I came back to this (unfortunately unanswered) question and found out this: Looking into "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories" of my QtGUI-Project (the executable) I see the following:

- QtGUI\build\QtGUI_autogen\include_Debug
- QtGUI\src\Main\include
- QtGUI\src\QtWidgets\include

and some more.

But the required `ui_MainWidget.h` is located inside `QtGUI\build\QtWidgets_autogen\include_Debug`, which is not set as additional include directory.
I added it manually and everything works.

**How do I need to modify my CMakeLists.txt file to have this directory automatically set for my additional include directories?**

PS: I also checked [Implementing Qt project through CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989448/implementing-qt-project-through-cmake) but couldn't find any relevant difference in the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more digging I realized that the way the AUTOUIC target property is designed, CMake is looking in specific directories to find the generated UI header file. These directories are *automatically added to the target’s INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES*, which was `[projectname]_autogen\include_Debug` as mentioned above.
This is only done for each target and not across targets.

One option would be to set the target property `AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR` to a directory that can easily be included without any special string:

```
set_target_properties(QtWidgets
                      PROPERTIES AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

However, the problem with that approach is that I have two targets so the `mocs_compilation.cpp` will be both put in the same directory and thus one gets overwritten. In the end I had to do something like

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
                      PROPERTIES AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/QtWidgets")
```

which makes the whole thing superfluous.

Answering my latest edited question, on how to include the other targets autogen-include directory:
`$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/QtWidgets_autogen/include_Debug>`
can be used inside `target_include_directories` for the `QtGUI`-target, which results in

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        Main/include
    $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/QtWidgets_autogen/include_Debug>
    $<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/QtWidgets_autogen/include_Release>
)
```

Additionally, the code could be changed to use the classic `qt5_wrap_ui` and `qt5_wrap_cpp` approach, which would put the generated UI header files into my `QtGUI\build` directory.

**Edit / Addition**

Looking into "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories" of my QtGUI-Project (the executable) I can now see the following:

- QtGUI\build\QtGUI_autogen\include_Debug
- QtGUI\src\Main\include
- QtGUI\build\QtWidgets_autogen\include_Debug
- QtGUI\src\QtWidgets\include

and some more.